# How to set height to fill height of parent node?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to try to make an HTML table using pure CSS and `div`/`span` elements. I currently have the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAnnN/). However the table cell...

```
 .table .table-cell {
      float: left;
      padding: 0 10px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      display: table-cell;
 }
```

...elements don't fill the height of the parent row.

Please help me to resolve my problem.

**EDIT**: I make on pure CSS instead table element for increased performance.

**EDIT2**: Is it possible to simulate `colSpan` and `rowSpan`?

Comment: use table etc tags - I think the words 'rod', 'back', 'own', 'your' and 'for' come to mind

Comment: I'm not sure if you are being bound by an angry project manager to not use tables, but sorry, if you want to build something that looks like a table then just build a table. Why div's and span's?

Comment: Just an additional comment...who told you that not using a table would increase performance? That's not even remotely true.

Comment: Tables elements is very heavy HTML element.

Comment: That's not true. They used to be heavy in the old days, where systems would build layouts based on tables inside of tables inside of tables inside of tables etc.

Nowdays, just building a table to render a table is no different than using div's. In fact, based on your code, your method is actually a couple of bytes bigger than it would be with tables!

Comment: I have around 50 tables with 100 rows each one

Comment: Are they all nested inside each other and used for site layout? If not, then as I said before you are not increasing performance by using div's. It's not about how many tables you have, it's about why you are using them.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show you my code but I assure you that I add a new row in one of a table I get browser reflow whole page. And it takes 1 second.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28378/discussion-between-erik-and-asouthorn)

Comment: Seriously, just use a table.  Shoving tabular data into a bunch of divs is just as bad as using tables for layout.  This "performance boost" you speak of is completely imaginary.

Answer (score 1):

Table cells can not be floatet. Remove `float: left` from the `.table-cell` like in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAnnN/26/):

```
.table .table-cell {
    /* float: left; */
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead your style:

```
.table .table-cell {
      padding: 0 10px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      display: table-cell;
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try below code

```
.table .table-cell {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}
```